# coverity static code analysis across branches/projects

Tags: static-analysis, coverity

We have product code which is maintained across multiple branches. We want to run the Coverity analysis separately for all the branches.
As most of the code is same on all the branches, I want to use the analysis result of one branch to another.
So the question here is..Can we related two snapshots from the different projects in the Coverity Connect? So that for any new branch created I can compare it with the analysis result of previous branch snapshot.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe that facts collected about one branch are true of the other branch?  Example:  branch 1:  int x[7]; i=5; x[i]...; clearly no subscript fault.  branch 2:  int x[7]; i=8; ... if you assume that branch 2 has no subscript errors based on branch 1 properties, you will get the wrong answer.  A *one character* change can radically alter the properties of a software system.

Comment: @Ira Baxter - Actually you can make a lot of interferences across branches, most of the code is the same after-all.  You can also come up with lists of defects that are common to both branches or unique.

Comment: @MarkRobinson: yes, *defects* may carry usefully across branches.  A diagnosis of an error at a place in one branch are hints that the same error may exist in that place in the other branch.  And, if you look and are wrong, you only lose a little time.  What is NOT true, is that *absence* of error in a place in one branch, is a good hint that there is no error in that place in the other, as my trivial example was intended to show.  So you need to be really careful about what inferences you carry across branches.

Comment: @Ira Baxter, oh absolutely, you can't prove that a defect is fixed because it's missing in another branch.  After all, the world of C, macros, and platform specific builds still exists.  

On the other hand, if we add the dimensionality of time we can do some interesting things.  We can infer that a defect was fixed in v2.1 if it only exists in v2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Comparing defects across branches/projects isn't a first class operation but it can be done using the web-services interface (coverity connect).

Get the defects for project `A` using the snapshot scope of `last()`, then get the defects for project `B` also using `last()`.  Now you need to some set operations, this is quite easy if you join the sets using the merge key field.

So `A intersect B` on `merge key` will give defects in both,
`A - B` on `merge key` will give defects only in `A`.